# Prototype: observing 2 elements and pass different parameters?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

CI have this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < toObserve.length; i++) {

    var elems = toObserve[i].split('###');
    var elementToObserve = elems[0];
    var imageToUse = elems[1];

    $(elementToObserve).observe('click', respondToClick);
}

function respondToClick(event) {

    var element = event.element();
}
```

In the respondToClick function I need a different image (imageToUse) for each elementToObserve. How can I do that? Can I pass a param or something?

Thanks!

**Addition:** I tried what Diodeus suggested, but it seems that only the last passed parameter is used, when any of the elements I observe is clicked. Whats wrong or is the way I want to do it not the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function:

```
$(elementToObserve).observe('click', function(event) {
    var yourVar = "moo";
    respondToClick(event,yourVar)
});
```

Comment: On the other hand, I debugged a bit and when the respondToClick function is called, it really adds 2 different images to the function, clicking the observed elemnts has the same image all the time though. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the specialised [`bindAsEventListener`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/bindAsEventListener/).

```
$(elementToObserve).observe('click',
    respondToClick.bindAsEventListener(imageToUse)
);
```

The bound arguments will then be passed after the `event` parameter.

```
function respondToClick(event, imageToUse)
{
    var element = event.element();
    element.src = imageToUse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by simply assigning my variable to the element object:

```
elementToObserve.imageToUse = imageToUse;
```

Then in the observer function:

```
function respondToClick(event) {
    var imageToUse = event.target.imageToUse;
}
```

I haven't realized any drawbacks to this.